# Finding unprintable characters and printing out their hex form in C

Tags: c, string, state-machine

I currently have a finite state machine which analyzes a long string, separates the long string by white space, and analyzes each token to either octal, hex, float, error, etc.

Here is a brief overview of how I analyze each token:

```
enum state mystate = start_state; 

while (current_index <= end_index - 1) { // iterate through whole token
    switch (mystate) {
        case 0:
            // analyze first character and move to appropriate state
            // cases 1-5 represent the valid states, if error set mystate = 6
        case 6: // this is the error state
            current_index = end_index - 1; // end loop
            break; 
    }
    current_index++;
}
```

At the end of this loop, I analyze what state my token fell under, for example if the token didn't fit into any category and it went to state 6 (the error state):

```
if (mystate == 6) {
    // token is char pointer to string token
    fprintf(stdout, "Error: \" %s \" is invalid\n", token);
}
```

Now, I am supposed to print out unprintable characters from 0x20 and under, such as start-of-text, start-of-header, etc. in their hex form, such as [0x02] and [0x01]. I found a good list of the ASCII unprintable characters from 0x20 and under here: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/start-of-header-ascii-code-1.html

Firstly, I am confused how to even type the unprintable characters into the command line. How does one type an unprintable character as a command line argument for my program to analyze?

After that hurdle, I know that the unprintable characters will fall into state 6, my error state. So I have to modify my error state if statement slightly. Here is my thought process of how to do so in pseudo code:

```
if (mystate == 6) {
    if (token is equal to unprintable character) {
        // print hex form, use 0x%x for formatting
    } else {
        // still error, but not unprintable so just have original error statement
        fprintf(stdout, "Error: \" %s \" is invalid\n", token); 
    }
}
```

Another thought I had was:

```
if (mystate == 6) {
    if (the token's hex value is between 0x01 and 0x20) {
        // print hex form, use 0x%x for formatting
    } else {
        // still error, but not unprintable so just have original error statement
        fprintf(stdout, "Error: \" %s \" is invalid\n", token); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a sane libc you would use

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
if (!isprint((int)ch) {
    unsigned x = ch;
    printf ("[0x%02x]", 0xff&(int)ch);
}
...
```

to find non-printable ascii characters, assumed that `char ch` is your current input character.

To use them in a command line you could use printf(1) from the command line.

```
printf '\x02'|xxd
0000000: 02
```

There you see the STX character. BTW. There is an excellent manual page about ascii (`ascii(7)`)!

So as a complete command line:

```
YOUR_Program "`printf '\x02\x03\x18\x19'`"
```

(The xxd was just to show what comes out of printf, as it is non-printable). xxd is just a hexdump utility, similar to od.

**Note:** When you really want unprintable input, it is more convenient to take the input either from a file, or from stdin. That simplifies your program call:

```
printf '\x02\x03\x18\x19'|YOUR_Program
```

Comment: I a still a bit confused how to use the command line argument printf. And I don't believe I'm formatting the hex correctly, for when I tried the input '\x02'|xxd, it printed out hex code 0x6a758c8d. I'm obviously doing something wrong, how do I properly get it in the form 0x02, for example.

Comment: @Bret The `xxd` should just show what comes out of the printf command, through the pipe.

Comment: Got it. So I type in ./myprogramname "`printf '\x02 \x03 \x18 \x19'`" (and keep testing \x04 through \x20). Now, I need a little help with the formatting in my print statement in my error check. I keep getting really long hex numbers, such as 0x76149c8e, instead of the correct 0x02 through 0x20 format. I currently have: fprintf(stdout, "Error: \" %s \" is invalid, hex: [0x%02x]\n", token, token);

Comment: @Bret The output looks as if token is a pointer not a character (or integer). `%s` wants a `char*` type. I assume that is your `token`. Then you would get the first character by `(int)token[0]`. So it looks like `printf("\"%s\" has invalid hex code [0x%02x]\n", token, (int)token[0]);`

Comment: Your welcome. Such questions remind me of the far past, when I was young and innocent ;)

Comment: Weaknesses with `if (!isprint((int)ch) { printf ("%02x", (int)ch);` : 1) With signed `char` and `ch < 0`, this will certainly print out 4 or 8 hex digits.  2) repeated use to output of strings with printable text can be indistinguishable from strings with unprintable text.  `"0d"` and `"\n"` output the same.

Comment: @chux, you are right. Thanks for the hint. I changed the line.

Answer (score -2):

One piece of your puzzle is printing in hex.

```
Printf("%02x", 7);
```

This prints the two digit hex value 07.

Another piece is detecting non printable.

If (c < 20).

This translates as if the character has any value less than a space.

You might research the isprint function as there are some unprintable characters that are greater than space.

Good luck.  Welcome to c.

Comment: `"%02x"` prints _at least_ 2 hexadecimal digits.  Should the character have a value less than 0, more than 2 digits will be printed.  Suggest `printf("%02hhx", 7);` or `printf("%02x", (unsigned char) ch);`